# Parsing item list line by line then character by character

Tags: c

I have to parse a game file that has this format:

```
ItemID      = 3288 # This is a comments and begins with '#' character.
Name        = "a magic sword"
Description = "It has some ancient runic inscriptions."
Flags       = {MultiUse,Take,Weapon}
Attributes  = {Weight=4200,WeaponType=1,WeaponAttackValue=48,WeaponDefendValue=35}
# A line can also begin with this character and it should be ignored.
```

and I have to parse it's data and put them into variables. I have tried many things, and I've been told that I will have to read the file line by line, then read each line character by character (so I'm able to read until '#' character) and then read the result word by word following the pattern. I have done this:

```
void ParseScriptFile(FILE* File) {
    char Line[1024];
    while (fgets(Line, sizeof(Line), File)) {

    }
    fclose(File);
}
```

I think I should read the lines inside the while loop but I don't know how would I read until # character is reached and if it does not exist just continue looping line through line. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I think this is homework and the lecturer gave you some skeleton code to get you started

Comment: No, it is not homework. I'm trying to parse a VERY big file with almost 30.000 lines. I'm not used to C so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Do you know how to loop through an array? `Line[1024]` is a character array you can step through inside the `while` loop; and you can `break` from that inner loop when you encounter a `'#'`.

Comment: Side note (since you're apparently learning): don't close a file inside a function that you haven't opened inside the same function. close the file at the same level/scope where you opened it (ditto memory allocation and various others).

Comment: Is it a loop? After Attributes line do you start over ItemID again?

Comment: Yes, there are over 8000 of items that I have to parse

Answer (score 0):

Use sscanf, like I did two for you

```
 void ParseScriptFile(FILE* File) {
    char Line[1024];
    int ItemID; // variable to store ItemId
    char name[40]; // string to store Name
    while (fgets(Line, sizeof(Line), File)) {
            sscanf(Line, "ItemID = %d", &ItemID);
            sscanf(Line, "Name = %[^n]s", name); // ^n upto newline
    }       
    printf("ItemId= %d\n", ItemID);
    printf("Name= %s", name);

    fclose(File);
}
```

Comment: But I need to handle the comments inside the line, code you shared doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Here's more or less workable code.  Reading lines with `fgets()` is correct.  You can then eliminate empty lines and comment lines trivially. If the line ends with a comment, you can convert the `#` into a null byte to ignore the comment. Then you need to scan for the entries name field (assume there are no spaces in the name part, to the left of the equals sign), and the `=` and the value on the right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static
void ParseScriptFile(FILE *File)
{
    char Line[1024];
    while (fgets(Line, sizeof(Line), File))
    {
        if (Line[0] == '#' || Line[0] == '\n')
            continue;
        char *comment_start = strchr(Line, '#');
        if (comment_start != NULL)
            *comment_start = '\0';
        char name[64];
        char value[1024];
        if (sscanf(Line, " %63s = %1023[^\n]", name, value) == 2)
            printf("Name = [%s] Value = [%s]\n", name, value);
        else
            printf("Mal-formed line: [%s]\n", Line);
    }
    fclose(File);
}

int main(void)
{
    ParseScriptFile(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

The program reads from standard input.  An example run from your data file yielded:

```
Name = [ItemID] Value = [3288 ]
Name = [Name] Value = ["a magic sword"]
Name = [Description] Value = ["It has some ancient runic inscriptions."]
Name = [Flags] Value = [{MultiUse,Take,Weapon}]
Name = [Attributes] Value = [{Weight=4200,WeaponType=1,WeaponAttackValue=48,WeaponDefendValue=35}]
```

Note the space at the end of the ItemID value; there was a space before the `#` symbol.

If you need to handle strings that could themselves contain `#` symbols, you have to work harder (`Curse = "You @##$%!" # Language, please!`).  Parsing an entry such as the value for `Attributes` is a separate task for a separate function (callable from this one).  Indeed, you should be calling one or more functions to process each name/value pair.  You probably also need some context passed to the `ParseScriptFile()` function so that the data can be saved appropriately.  You wouldn't want to contaminate clean code with unnecessary global variables, would you?

Comment: This was so useful. I have another doubt tho. In the file I have an awful lot of ítems to parse and they are defined in the same file divided just by a newline. Is there a way the file can be parsed "by blocks" or something? It would be 5 + 1 lines (5 plus the newline). I don't know how I would parse this...

Comment: You'll have to think about how best to do the grouping.  When do comments appear?  You presumably don't count them in the groups of 5.  Are the lists of names the same 5 (ItemID, Name, Description, Flags, Attributes) always the same, or do they vary from group to group?  There are so many unspoken rules that could be in force that it's hard to know what's best, but you can include some sort of counter, or track by the names of the fields, or whatever seems best.  You know the data — those of us over here have very little information to work on.

Comment: Note that dramatically altering/expanding the question would not be fair.  If need be, you can ask a new question.  Don't go creating a chameleon question — a question that changes as people try to help.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's like my second question in SO and I'm still trying very hard to learn C but I keep failing miserably as a human being. I made a mistake, it was 4 lines + 1 (newline). The ítems all have 4+1 lines. Every item has an id, a name, at least one flag and at least one attribute. The format is the same in every item.

Comment: I included this [https://pastebin.com/Vz2h217g](https://pastebin.com/Vz2h217g) so you can see what I am talking about.

Comment: You have blank lines separating groups of entries; that makes it easy. The description is optional; the other 4 seem to be mandatory. When reading, you have to worry about mistakes in the data.  Entries out of sequence, repeated, missing, misspelled. You’ll already have a structure to store the information. You now know how to handle comments. It should all be a SMOP — a simple matter of programming.